# How to listen for when HTML5 video stops playing in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I found this [similar question here](http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/yvne6fnt/), however the answer did not work in my case.

**My JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/yvne6fnt/**

HTML

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: -1;">
<video id="hero_video" controls="" autoplay="autoplay" preload poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <source id="mp4" src="http://leongaban.com/v6/videos/clouds.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source id="webm" src="http://leongaban.com/v6/videos/clouds.webm" type="video/webm">
  <source id="ogv" src="http://leongaban.com/v6/videos/clouds.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video>
```

JS

```
$("#hero_video").bind('stop', function(e) {
    console.log('stopped');
    alert('stopped');
}, true);

/*
$("video").bind('stop', function(e) {
    console.log('stopped');
    alert('stopped');
}, true);
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you remove the 3rd argument from your function:

```
$("#hero_video").bind('stop', function(e) {
    console.log('stopped');
    alert('stopped');
});
```

Notice that this will only be triggered at the beginning and of the video. If you want to also trigger an event on pause, you have to also include the pause event:

```
$("#hero_video").bind('stop pause', function(e) {
    console.log('stopped');
    alert('stopped');
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvne6fnt/8/

Not sure why this works though, since the default for that argument is `true`. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Oh, I noticed that I had to use `stop pause` instead of just `stop` for it to find the event for some reason

Comment: Yeah, stop is only triggered at the end of the video.

Comment: no stop is no video event. you may want to use 'ended'